# Stitching a photo below a batch of photos

Tags: photo-management, photo

I am sure there would be a simple command for this however I have not been able to find one.

Basically I would like to stitch a photo below another photo with no overlap. Also ideally I would like a command that can automate this process for 200 top images where the same bottom image is stitched. All images have the same width so no transformation is required.

I am looking for a program something like "stitch -below top.png bottom.png", I have explored options like Montage but can not seem to get it to work as required. Looking for advise.

Comment: Um...What exactly you want to do want to do with this question? Could you please be a _little_ more precise about what you want to do (eg...program name, etc.)

Comment: @packpatfan, the question is clear for me. He is looking for a program to perform that task.

Comment: I suppose, but he could have been a bit more concise about stating that in his question. To me it appeared that he was looking for a plugin/command for an image editor (Unmentioned).

Comment: I am looking for a program something like "stitch -below top.png bottom.png", I have explored options like Montage but can not seem to get it to work as required. Looking for advise.

Comment: Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to open a terminal and `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`.

Now place all your images in the same folder so you can easily access them from the terminal. Put the top images all in their own folder and keep the bottom image elsewhere to simplify things.

Type `cd DIRNAME`, you need to replace DIRNAME with the name of the folder the pictures are stored in, for example `/home/mark/collating` is what I use for this purpose.

Now that your shell is in the right folder and imagemagick is installed we use the following to stick the images together:

`convert -append image1.jpg image2.jpg output.jpg`

This will take the two images named image1 and image2 and stick image2 on the bottom of image1, saving the result as a file named output.jpg.

To automate this you can use a script like this one. You need to change the variables so they point to the right places.

```
#! /bin/bash

#   Replace the values of these variables with the locations of your tops and the bottom.
# The output directory must already exist!
#   "~/" is a shortcut for your home dir, FYI.

TopsDir="~/collating/tops" #Only the TOP images should be in this folder!
BottomImg="~/collating/bottom.png"
OutputDir="~/collating/complete"

[ -d "$TopsDir" -a -d "$OutputDir" ] && [ -f "$BottomImg" ] || { echo "One of the paths you supplied wasn't valid."; exit 1;}

cd "$TopsDir"

for TopImg in *; do
    convert -append "$TopImg" "$BottomImg" "$OutputDir/$TopImg"
done
```

Copy and paste it into gedit or your text editor and **edit the variables** so that they point to the correct folders. (Or file for the bottom img.) Save it as `collator.sh`. It is convenient for the next steps if you save it in your home directory.

Now open a terminal and navigate to where you saved the file. (You're already there if you saved it in your home dir, otherwise type `cd /path/to/your/location`) Type `chmod +x collator.sh` to give the file execute permissions.

And now we get the work done:
Type `./collator.sh` to run the script; and you're done.

Comment: To automate this, make a file `filename.sh` in `DIRNAME`, and write (something like) `#!/bin/bash` [NewLine] `for FILE in ./*.jpg; do convert -append "${FILE}" bottom.png "${FILE}"` [NewLine]
`done`. Then mark the file as executable (right click > permissions) and run. This (I think) should do it for all files, **but will overwrite the originals, so make a copy!** (I don't know how to manipulate the second `"${FILE}"` to produce a new name  -- `"${FILE}2"` gives `filename.jpg2`, else I got errors. I hope it will help anyways!)

Comment: WOW I got it working Mark!!!! You guys have saved me days!! This is helpful beyond belief, I don't think I have ever been this happy with the internet! Thankyou Mark and Rasmus.